# Why is Minecraft giving an OpenGL error?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently got Minecraft but not from the website, I paid for a code and everything seemed ok. When I tried to play the game a thing came up saying it crashed and then a message popped up saying The game crashed whilst initializing game

> Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GLFW error 65542: WGL: The driver does not appear to support OpenGL.

Comment: Which website did you get this from?

Comment: "but not from the website"? You should never buy Minecraft anywhere else than on minecraft.net! Immediately refund that payment!

Comment: Well I got the code from amazon and it has worked for other people one person I know. It worked for them fine. The person I asked for help that has Minecraft said it would not matter if I got it from Minecraft.net and she also got her brother that was good with computers and it still did not work.

Comment: Using gift cards or buying it directly is just a matter of personal taste. The game would still be the same. Just don't buy it on some 3rd party key stores and only download the game from minecraft.net.

Comment: Just to be clear - did you download the game not from the website, or did you buy a code not from the website and then download the game from the website?

Comment: Do you have any shaders enabled? I have seen those cause these kinds of errors on otherwise fine systems.

Comment: No I do no have any shaders enabled.

Comment: @iMalinowski doesn't seem like that would be the case; this seems like a fresh vanilla install that fails to boot

Comment: Could you perhaps tell us the specs on your device?

Answer (score 25):

It looks like your graphics card doesn't support OpenGL or your drivers are outdated.

- For dedicated graphics cards, go to the card manufacturer's site (Nvidia, AMD etc.) and download the driver for your card and OS.
- For integrated graphics, go to your motherboard manufacturer's site
  and download the driver for your motherboard and OS. Make sure you download the correct driver because quite a lot of older motherboard don't have Win10 drivers for example and installing Win7 drivers will cause problems.

There's also a guide on how to upgrade your drivers on [Minecraft's page](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/928493-updating-video-card-drivers).

Comment: @BaneBerry If using windows, you can determine what type of graphics card you have by using [this question from SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com/q/184932/210293)

Comment: you can also find out by going to the Device Manager under Display devices i believe, or by going to your system properties in File Explorer.