# My minecraft is crashing once i launch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I recently got a new laptop, but when i downloaded and tried playing minecraft, it kept on crashing after trying to launch. It gave me his error report:

**The game crashed whilst initializing game
Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GLFW error 65542: WGL: The driver does not appear to support OpenGL**

If required, I can post the full crash report and any other information you guys need.

Comment: The full crash report is here: https://pastebin.com/GtMsi8h1 
Even if the solution is simple, can you at least explain what seems to be causing it to crash, so I have a better understanding of how to solve this in the future

Comment: Usually the laptop specs would be helpful, except that in this case it's just the usual, MC-297. In short: Your graphics card can't run Minecraft (or you don't have the correct driver for it).

Comment: Not a dupe, just related.. the other Q does not contain this error message.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why is Minecraft giving an OpenGL error?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/348643/4797)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no coding expert, but I know for sure Open GL is critical for rendering graphics. I'm pretty sure your crash report also says that **"this driver does not appear to support OpenGL"**. This is not an issue with Minecraft, but an issue with your laptop, specifically your driver. The solution is, that you reinstall your NVIDIA graphics driver (search it up if you don't know).

If reinstalling still does not work, contact the IT company you bought it from, or any technical support service, and tell them that the graphics driver does not appear to support OpenGL (plus any other details concerning this issue)