# Why doesn't my Minecraft launch when I press play on the Minecraft launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have spent what seems like 1 month of researching. So when I try to play Minecraft a few months ago, it works completely fine. Last week, I tried to play Minecraft and it doesn't want to launch. I press the play button on the launcher, it closes the launcher but after a few seconds, it doesn't launch Minecraft, it just goes back to the launcher and says Minecraft has crashed.

Can anyone help me to fix this? Also, the Minecraft screen doesn't show up, it just goes back to the launcher.

Edit: I have found the crash folder, anyone who knows coding and stuff please help me

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GLFW error 65542: WGL: The driver does not appear to support OpenGL
    at cuo.b(SourceFile:199)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallbackI.callback(GLFWErrorCallbackI.java:36)
    at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokePPPP(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1714)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1897)
    at cuo.<init>(SourceFile:81)
    at dnr.a(SourceFile:19)
    at cyc.au(SourceFile:464)
    at cyc.b(SourceFile:394)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:155)
```

Comment: What error message did you get? There should be a pop-up to display the error message. Furthermore, you can get more information by enabling the debug console.

Comment: @FabianRöling I guess that with the edit of the error message, it is more accurate now?

Comment: Voting to reopen as the crash log is now in the question. However, this appears to be a duplicate of [Why is Minecraft giving an OpenGL error?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/348643/4797) "It looks like your graphics card doesn't support OpenGL or your drivers are outdated."

Comment: I think that you should show your computer to a professional.

Answer (score -1):

**Minecraft Crashing?**
**To fix your problems please try the following options**

- Try deleting your Mods from your mod folder for Minecraft, Mods could be causing an error in Minecraft's physics, images, listings, save games, etc
- If the Problem Persists try finding the save games folder in Minecraft using File explorer, remove the save games and try loading the game
- If the above fail try re-downloading the game, but make sure that you delete your orginal copy first or else the new Minecraft would overlap with the previous
  *Thank you,*

Comment: none of these actually worked for me. minecraft crashes but doesnt show me an error, i reinstalled the game and still didnt work. : (